Why ifconfig command does not work due to permission denied when you connect to public WiFi or SSID?
This might be a bit stupid/naive question but I was at a conference event and after I connected to Free WiFi, I tried ifconfig in cmd of my cellphone via Termux and it did not work as follows:
> ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1  (UNSPEC)

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet XX.XX.75.132  netmask 255.255.224.0  broadcast XX.XX.95.255
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

before writing this post I thought used ipconfig but now I'm more curious why they closed/banned ifconfig command. Do they close this command when they configure the DHCP server to provide free internet access for the public or thesis configured somewhere else? and why?
Edit1: as @Mircea Vutcovici proposed and commented

I installed getfacl via Termux on my cellphone and tried getfacl /proc/net/dev; it resulted in:


getfacl: /proc/net/dev: Permission denied


tried ls -lZd /proc/net/dev, it resulted in:


ls: cannot access '/proc/net/dev': Permission denied


It is not something the network did. It's on your computer; there's no mechanism in either wifi or dhcp to modify file permissions.

Thanks for migration of question to right community i was assuming problem is some setup in DHCP server.

Could you add the output of: getfacl /proc/net/dev and ls -lZd /proc/net/dev ? check also the audit.log and kernel log (dmesg).

I need to install for getfacl and let you know but for ls -lZd  i got permission denied. FYI, I used cmd of my cellphone in  terminal. I was connected to internet via modem-router.

Do you run the ifconfig command inside a container?

Please post the entire output, not your interpretation. For example the ifconfig error is about a permission denied when opening a specific file

@MirceaVutcovici I just updated my post and tried what you proposed in a comment.

I included the tag Termux in my post, which may draw better attention. At first, I thought it was because of Wi-Fi, but now I think there's something wrong with my cellphone.

The error you see is about opening for reading the /proc/net/dev file, which contains network interfaces statistics.
The error you see mentions that you don't have access to that file and the consequence is that the network statistics, like packet counters, are missing.
You could try the modern replacement of ifconfig, which is using Netlink to get those stats from kernel:
ip -s -s -d -h address show

DHCP has nothing to do with your issue. Do you run the ifconfig command in a container?
Edit: Because you are running the command inside a container with limited access, you have limited access. It has nothing to do with Wi-fi.
If you read Termux FAQ, they mention this limitation:

Why does htop or netstat not work on my device
In order to stop leaking sensitive information via side channels,
Android has blocked access to certain interfaces in /proc. This is
done for your privacy.
Specifically:
/proc/net/* /proc/loadavg /proc/stat /proc/uptime /proc/version
/proc/vmstat And few others.
Restrictions vary between Android OS versions. Thus Android 7 is less
restrictive than 8/9/10+. You can use root to bypass them.


I have also tried this solution, but it returns useless outputs screenshot

I researched using GenAI tools (e.g., ChatGPT), and it proposed installing some wireless-tools and trying ipconfig ifconfig iwconfig. It also proposed ip addr from the iproute2 package, but it was not working. I also proposed using netstat -ie. So far, all outputs have been either permission denied or rubbish! IDK what is the problem with my cellphone as a device. I can't even get results of simple  ipconfig or ifconfig it is kind of ridiculous.

It's an Android limitation, created for security purposes.
